# PCM_SIGNED 8000.0 HZ, 16 bit, mono, 2 bytes/frame, 48000.0 frames/second, big-endian from PCM-SIGNED 48000.0 HZ, 16 bit, mono, 2 bytes/frame, big end

Tags: audio-processing

How can I resolve the following issue: Unsupported conversion: PCM_SIGNED 8000.0 HZ, 16 bit, mono, 2 bytes/frame, 48000.0 frames/second, big-endian from PCM-SIGNED 48000.0 HZ, 16 bit, mono, 2 bytes/frame, big endian

On Mac High Sierra (10.13.6) I am running JAudio, a digital signal processing software implementing a number of common feature extraction algorithms for analysing audio files. The above message appears when I finally hit 'Extract Features'.
I have been converting the original .wav audio files numerous times using all sorts of different converters (VLC, iTunes, WAV converter, etc) and looked into codec but had to give up due to lack of knowledge and IT skills.

I would be grateful for any directions on what I would need to install or look for in order to resolve the issue.
Many thanks

------------ details of one of the audio files I used to extract from:
SAMPLING RATE: 48.0 kHz
BIT DEPTH: 16 bits
CHANNELS: mono
FRAME SIZE: 16 bits
FRAME RATE: 48000.0 frames per second
ENCODING: PCM_SIGNED
BYTE ORDER: big-endian
PROPERTIES: {}
SAMPLES PER CHANNEL: 2174706 samples

Comment: try to do the conversion using another audio editor first and then have JAudio do the feature extraction part.

Comment: I converted the original audio files to wav and aiff prior to loading them into JAudio. I used VLC, iTunes and WAV converter but with no success.

Comment: the error message says that JAudio can't convert your file(s) from 48Khz to 8KHz (since everything else is the same, I focused on the sampling rates only), but I'm suggesting to not use JAudio at all to do the conversion. Use Audacity and convert your file there and only then load the file(s) in JAudio.

Comment: Thank you guys for your help. I ended up using a PC which resolved the problem.